# Use of profanity

Tags: discussion

This is a question about the use of profanity on the site.

I am sure this must have been specified somewhere else. Obviously, abuse is not allowed. But profanity/cuss words can be used cleverly. I admit that I cannot remember anyone doing so. Allusions to such words perhaps.

I have recently seen a new user whose name contains a profanity. Is that something that is allowed? Is it something that should be allowed? Is it something that we as a community (or moderators within it) control?

Comment: To your second paragraph: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/6344/5373

Comment: [Here's one.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67989/i-can-do-anything)

Comment: I just stumbled over this, and the second paragraph reminded me of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376774/ (I made quite some comments there ... the tl:dr is: Calm down...)

Comment: @Marco13, why would you assume I'm not calm?

Comment: @DrXorile This wasn't targeting you specifically - you just asked a question about a policy, neutrally. My comments in the Q/A linked above should make clear that the answer given here (~"No profanity in names") is simply unenforcable. Sure, you cannot buy a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Pajero in Spain, but we're talking about *millions* of user names, where "profanities" may be disguised up to a point where every decision is essentially arbitrary.

Answer (score 8):

### Users having profanity in their names is prohibited

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103293/399694): a user got their name changed from “fuckvimmeanpeople” to something else by a moderator. The user changed it to “fuckmeanpeopleingeneral” after that and then got banned. Quote from the answer about this:

> If [the user changing their name to something inappropriate] recurs, we'll need an IP ban.

**“fucking garbage community” is certainly inappropriate. I have mod-flagged that user’s post as “Inappropriate username” and I presume that the user’s name will be changed by a mod.**

Comment: I have renamed the account. It's now called "garbage community", which is still rude, but I think tolerable. I expect the user will either get over their annoyance at PSE and change their name to something more sensible, or stay angry and stop using PSE; in either case the problem is likely to be self-limiting. (Or I guess they might melt down completely and get a lengthy suspension or something of the sort.)

Comment: For the official policy on profanity in general (not just in usernames), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232.

Comment: In the spirit of the question, should this answer be edited with ***?

Comment: @DrXorile I've left the name as-is so as to be as clear as possible what I'm talking about.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think that there are several interpretations as to why this username was chosen in the first place, but at any rate nothing indicates that PSE was targeted, a username is chosen for all SE sites. When we see profanity, it is natural to feel targeted, but there is often another explanation - e.g., this user  might have been mad at the whole SE community, or even at the actual [Garbage Community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Garbage_Community) :)

Comment: I think there are indications that PSE was the specific target; the user was cross about things that happened on PSE to another account he had. But as a general point, you're right: one shouldn't jump to conclusions too quickly.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I haven't seen this user or anything that happened here but it is worth noting that you can change your username _per community_, in fact you can have completely different "profiles" per each stack if you click "save changes for just this community" instead of "save changes".